# How to output the number of restaurants in each category (such as: Italian, Japanese, Chinese)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bigdata, kaggle

Using python and pandas, how can I output the number of restaurants in each category? I have a datset of Restaurants and column called "Categories" which contains "restaurants" such as (Italian, Chinese...).

I want to count the TOP 10 number of restaurants from the most popular to the least.

The data is stored in a variable "filename" which is csv file.

My Approach:

```
def myrest(filename, city):

restaurants = filename[filename['categories'].str.contains('Restaurants')]
restaurants.loc[restaurants.categories.str.contains('Italian'),   'category'] = 'Italian'
restaurants.loc[restaurants.categories.str.contains('Japanese'), 'category'] = 'Japanese'

print(restaurants.category[:10])
```

Output should be like : 
Italian: 350 (350 signifies the number of Italian restaurants in the city), 
Japanese: 250,
Korean: 140,
Turkish: 77
....

I am getting only the names of the restaurants but not the count of how many there are for example in "Toronto".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the values in the category column:

```
 restaurants.categories.value_counts()
 # or
 restaurants.groupby('categories').count()
```

You will get a table of the restaurant type and the number of times it is in the column.

Comment: Hi @eitrheim thank you for your answer. I also want the name of each restaurant. For example: Italian: 210, Japanese: 550 etc